# Python - Multiprocessing getting stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch, pool

I am trying to perform certain operations on the MNIST dataset in parallel. With the multiprocessing, it gets stuck and never ends. I tried putting the close and join functions inside or outside the for loop. I also tried putting the pool instantiation inside the function, doesn't seem to work either. What am I doing wrong here? No idea where should I be looking to solve this. Thank you very much for your help in advance

```
class MnistPartialDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, transform=None):
        self.data = data
    def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.data[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

def create_tasks(train_pool, test_pool):
    train_thread_result = []
    start = time.time()
    for k, v in train_tasks.items():
        tc_data = train_pool.map_async(test_function, v)
        train_thread_result.append(tc_data)
    train_pool.close()
    train_pool.join()
    for i in range(len(train_thread_result)):
        train_dataset[i] = MnistPartialDataset(train_thread_result[i].get())
    end = time.time()
    print("tc time: " + str(end-start))

    test_thread_result = []
    start = time.time()
    for k, v in test_tasks.items():
        tc_data = test_pool.map_async(test_function, v)
        test_thread_result.append(tc_data)
    test_pool.close()
    test_pool.join()
    for i in range(len(test_thread_result)):
        test_dataset[i] = MnistPartialDataset(test_thread_result[i].get())
    end = time.time()
def main():
    train_pool =  multiprocessing.Pool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
    test_pool =  multiprocessing.Pool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
    create_tasks(train_pool, test_pool)
    pool.close()
    pool.terminate()
```

Comment: It's difficult to interpret some of your variables. What're the values of `train_tasks` and `MnistPartialDataset`? Is there a reason you're foregoing the typical `with` statement of multiprocessing and opting to control the pool resources manually? Also, if I understand your goal, you might be able to use `imap` as a more concise alternative.

Comment: It would be helpful to see `test_function` since, at least in my experience, hung pools are often caused by hung threads/processes.

Comment: train_tasks is a dictionary of list. Each list contains 2 classes of data of the MNIST dataset. Each item is a tuple of (image_data, label). You may assume test_function is some elemental operations on the image data. Would using the with statement solve the problem?

I simply followed the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224000/multiprocessing-pool-with-a-for-loop?rq=1